# How to design a stress test for e-commerce application with jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am conducting a stress testing for a web application but I am quite confused how should I design the test cycle. So I have a test script with few controllers for example homepage, login, product catalogue and a uniform random timer. But How long and how many time should I run the the stress test to make a proper decision. Also for example I am using ultimate thread group for testing and how many user should add each time and how long the ramp up, hold time and shutting time can be for a proper result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) is about finding the boundaries of your application, the simplified approach is:

1. Design your test to simulate real user(s) activities with 100% accuracy, JMeter should produce the same requests as the real browser, you can cross check the requests sent by JMeter with "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)
2. Start with 1 virtual user
3. [Gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/)
4. Look into correlation of increasing load (i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) listener or equivalent) with the other performance metrics, the main ones are response time (i.e. [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime) or equivalent) and number of hits per second (i.e. [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) or equivalent)

On well behaved system when you increase the number of users the number of hits per second should increase proportionally, response time should remain the same, no errors should occur.

However if your system under test has limited hardware/scaling capabilities at certain point of time you will face the situation when the number of virtual users will be growing and the number of hits per second will remain the same or go down or errors will start occurring. This means that you found the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)